# JavaScript - For loop over JSON returns 'Undefined'

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple for loop that returns `undefined`

Here is the code:

```
  var optionName = '';

     for(var i=0; i<extras.length; i++){
          optionName = extras[i].optionName;
     }
     console.log(optionName);

     //      console.log(extras[0].optionName); >> Drinks
    //       console.log(extras[1].optionName); >> Undefined
```

Here is `extras` Array:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your **extras** object?

Comment: @AlaEddineJEBALI It's the one in the picture, Array[2]

Comment: yes I see but to be able to check the issue with you, we need to see the *extra* object as returned in JSON response

Comment: Please don't post images, post text.

Comment: It looks like you are having a multidimensional array there.

Comment: You have the answer in the image.

Comment: Please check the updated code (last 2 lines)

Comment: FYI, you're looping over a javascript array of javascript objects ... JSON is a string and there is no JSON involved in anything you've posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have an array with 2 elements.

```
extras = [
  {key: value},
  [object0, object1, object2],
]
```

As you can see the first element in your extras array is an object and that object has the `key: optionName` with a `value: Drinks`. So when you call

```
console.log(extras[0].optionName);
```

it will return the value of Drinks.

Then your loop moves on to the next element in the array and looks for a `key: optionName` but since your second array element is an array, it can't find the key and returns undefined. Since I do not know what is contained in the objects of `extra[1]` I can't offer advice on how to rewrite your loop but above is the explanation for why you receive `undefined`.

You can simply add an `if` condition to filter undefined values:

```
if (extras[0].optionName) {
  console.log(extras[0].optionName);
}
```

As undefined is a `falsy` value in JS, anytime that you do not actually have a value there, it will simply not move into the `if` statement.

Of course, if you want this to work in the loop, replace the `[0]` with `[i]`.

Comment: What you said is 100% right, is there any way to filter undefined values and return only defined ones ? I believe an `if condition` would do the job !

Answer (score 1):

The first array element has optionName property, but not the second. So when you access to `extras[1].optionName` doesn't exist and the code return undefined.

Comment: Please check the updated code (last 2 lines). Still I don't know the solution!

Comment: Come on man! `extras[0]` is an object, is `extras[1]` another object? No, so you cannot do `extras[1].optionName`, maybe works `extras[1][0].optionName`

Answer (score 0):

The second item in the array is an array (Array[3]), not an object.  `optionName` is undefined on that item.

Comment: There is still no property called `optionName` on the second element in the array.  That element is an array (not an object).  I think you have attempted to merge two arrays somewhere prior to this code and have instead added the second array as an element.